# How can I open dropdown manually, under condition in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, dropdown

I would like to open dropdown only if condition is fulfilled. How can I do this? Now my code looks like:

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-click="vm.openDropdown()">
  open
</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" uib-dropdown-menu>
    <a class="dropdown-item d-inline-flex" ng-repeat="test in vm.tests">{{test}}</a>
  </div>
</div>

vm.openDropdown = openDropdown
vm.tests = [1, 2, 3, 4]

function openDropdown () {
    if (vm.test == true) {
////and here I need have condition if something is true, I do not want to open dropdown
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use `ng-disabled` : (if variable test is true you can't open dropdown)

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="vm.test">open
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" uib-dropdown-menu>
       <a class="dropdown-item d-inline-flex" ng-repeat="test in vm.tests">{{test}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```